# How to join two files based on partial string match of a column in awk

Tags: awk

I have two files like shown below which are tab-delimited:

file A

```
chr1   123,aa  aa b c d
chr1   234,dd  a  b c d
chr1   af,345,e aa b c d
chr1   456 a  b c d
....
```

file B

```
xxxx  abcd    chr1   123,dd    aa    c    d    e
yyyy  defg    chr1   aa,345    aa    e    f    g
...
```

And i need to join these two files based on keys $4 in fileB and $2 in fileA so the output looks like:

```
chr1   123,aa       aa    b    c    d    xxxx    abcd
chr1   234,dd       a     b    c    d    xxxx    abcd
chr1   af,345,e     aa    b    c    d    yyyy    defg
chr1   456          a    b    c    d
```

I am trying using the solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$4]=$1OFS$2;next}{$6=a[$2];print}' OFS='\t' fileb filea
```

and this works only when there is a complete match with $2 in fileA. Is there any solution to match strings separated by comma in $2 of fileA?

Comment: there are many things happening here with the columns. Try to explain this better.

Comment: if $4 in fileB matches with string separated by comma in $2 of fileA, add $1,$2 from fileB to $6 in fileA

Comment: where does `chr1   123,aa` come from in the expected output then?

Comment: 234 is probably 234,dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes there can't be multiple values from any given $2 of fileA appear in fileB:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR { fileB[$4] = $1 OFS $2; next }
{
    tail = ""
    split($2,fileA,/,/)
    for (i in fileA) {
        if (fileA[i] in fileB) {
            tail = OFS fileB[fileA[i]]
        }
    }
    print $0 tail
}

$ awk -f tst.awk fileB fileA
chr1    123,aa  aa      b       c       d       xxxx    abcd
chr1    234,dd  a       b       c       d
chr1    af,345,e        aa      b       c       d       yyyy    defg
chr1    456     a       b       c       d
```

Given your new input/output you'll want something more like this (untested):

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR {
    split($4,b,/,/)
    for (i in b) {
        fileB[b[i]] = $1 OFS $2
    }
    next
}
{
    tail = ""
    split($2,a,/,/)
    for (i in a) {
        if (a[i] in fileB) {
            tail = OFS fileB[a[i]]
        }
    }
    print $0 tail
}
```

Comment: `$(NF+1)` is better than tail.

Comment: that's true but it'll cause awk to recompile $0, reevaluate NF, and resplit into fields so there's an efficiency hit and the resulting value of NF will be wrong (`echo 'a' | awk '{$(NF+1)="b c"; print NF}'` will output 2 while `echo 'a' | awk '{tail="b c"; $0=$0 OFS tail; print NF}'` will output 3.

Comment: now $4 in fileB also has strings separated by comma

Comment: tested and not working with multiple strings to match in fileB as well

Comment: Right and I'm sure if you thought about it a tiny bit you could have figured out that'd be the result without actually having to test it. I edited my answer to address the new requirements. Really do put some effort into thinking about the solutions you're getting though and ask questions if you don't understand anything because a script that produces the output you expect given some specific input set is just the starting point to identifying a solution, not the end point as YMMV when you run it with real data wrt output, efficiency, memory, robustness, extensibility, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just store data from fileB and concat it in fileA when necessary:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {data[$4]=$1 FS $2; next}
     {
      split($2,a,","); 
      if (a[1] in data) {$0=$0 FS data[a[1]]}
     }1' fb fa
```

#### Test

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {data[$4]=$1 FS $2; next} {split($2,a,","); if (a[1] in data) {$0=$0 FS data[a[1]]}}1' fb fa
chr1   123,aa aa b c d xxxx abcd
chr1   234,dd a  b c d
chr1   345,ee aa b c d yyyy defg
chr1   456 a  b c d
```

Comment: if i understand it correct it matches only a[1] element. May be in the example it is correct that it has to match a[1]. However, in the original file it can match any element in the split array 'a' rather only a[1].

Comment: I shouldn't have answered this, because it is clear you are not giving details enough; instead, you keep adding more in comments. Edit your original question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$  awk -v c=',' 'NR==FNR{a[c $4 c]=$1 FS $2; next}
                        {for(k in a) if(c $2 c~k) $(NF+1)=a[k]}1' fileB fileA |
column -t


chr1  123,aa    aa  b  c  d  xxxx  abcd
chr1  234,dd    a   b  c  d
chr1  af,345,e  aa  b  c  d  yyyy  defg
chr1  456       a   b  c  d
```

Comment: Sorry again!! OP updated, just realized that $4 in fileB also has strings separated by comma.

Comment: this approach won't work in that case, but your example is wrong now.  fileB's `123,dd` should be match both line1 and line2 in fileA.

Comment: yes!! in that case it could add to both lines in fileA.